# haproxy server check %[dst_port]

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I want to load balance requests to the same port on three backends.  I have about 20 ports to forward, so I need a way to make it dynamic.  This is for load balancing our prod, pre-prod, qa, dev, unit test servers for multiple domains.  So, yes, I can do it using 20 backends, with 20 acls, and 20 use_backends.  But then forget it.  Too much hassle.

So, that is, I'd like to use a variable, to mean "the port that was requested".  I tried %[dst_port] because that seemed to work in some other situation.

I read one answer somewhere from Willy T, that if one leaves out the port, then it just forwards to the same port.

But it still needs either the service port, or the check port, which I don't know ahead of time, unless I bind to 20 different frontends.

> Error: server X has neither service port nor check port nor tcp_check rule
>   'connect' with port information. Check has been disabled.

eg.

```
listen load-balance
     bind :28080 
     bind :42080 
     bind :48080 
     bind :58080 
     bind :38080 
     mode http
     balance roundrobin
     option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ localhost
     server X 10.20.30.1 check %[dst_port]
     server Y 10.20.30.2 check %[dst_port]
     server Z 10.20.30.3 check %[dst_port]
```

You see, it needs a variable.  Is this possible?

(My problem is even more complicated because technically I need a map from destination port to check port, ideally, but if I could do this dynamic port trick, at least, then that's good enough for now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure it with

```
 server X 10.20.30.1 check port 80
 server Y 10.20.30.2 check port 80
 server Z 10.20.30.3 check port 80
```

You can set only one port to check the health or you use the "external-check command" to check your server with a own script...

Comment: external-check command sounds like the ticket, thanks

Comment: though after looking at the docs for this, it seems you only get the first bind port as a parameter. You can't pass the actual port that was called to your script, if there's more than one bind. Seems like there's no way to do what I want with haproxy, and that I need a separate backend or listen for each port 

Comment: It depends on what your requirements are. Is your server "healthy" when only all ports are working? then you can write a script that checks all at once.
When you say that these ports works independently. Your idea to separate these is the better way...

Comment: The bind port on the frontend sends to the same port on 3 backend servers (like in my question). So if there were a variable to say what port was hit, I could check that port.

Comment: Haproxy checks the server health independently. So there is no information about what request use which port. When I understand you correctly you want check every time in the request phase before the request goes to the server on the port that the request is using. This does not work for my understanding...